# Why is one migration showing up as to a blank site?

Tags: bug, status-completed, migration, moderator-tools

I was just looking at the statistics for migrated questions in the [Science Fiction & Fantasy](http://scifi.stackexchange.com) mod tools, and noticed this oddity:

[image: Screenshot]

The actual statistics, as visible to any 10k+ SFF user [here](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/tools/posts/migrated/away), are: 6 migrated to Worldbuilding, 2 to Literature, **2** to SFF meta, 1 to Movies & TV, 1 to Writers, and 1 to Aviation.

**Why is one of the meta migrations showing up with a blank icon rather than with the other?**

Both migrated questions were closed as duplicates on meta. Both were migrated by 5 community members without mod involvement. One of the stubs on main has since been deleted, but so have the stubs for some of the other migrated questions. I can't think of anything to explain this discrepancy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

CreationEdge is correct [that the URL format changed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/293038/why-is-one-migration-showing-up-as-to-a-blank-site/293039#293039), but the different scheme for meta domains isn't all that problematic here (more on that in a bit) - what was breaking this was the move from URLs that start with `http://` to those that start with `https://`. Please, feast your eyes on this:

```
substring(Comment, charindex('http://',Comment) + 7, charindex('/', Comment, charindex('http://',Comment) + 7) - (charindex('http://',Comment) + 7)) as [site]
```

...when the burning finally subsides, you'll find yourself blissfully free of the temptation to parse strings with SQL. Suffice to say, this did not extract the relevant domain from post history when there was a https prefix in play.

Fortunately, Jon Chan (with some help from m0sa and Craver) endured the searing pain and fixed this up a week or so ago, and the new logic correctly identifies both old http and new https links.

Now that just leaves the change in meta domains to worry about... And since the old domain name is still an alias for those meta sites, the system is able to retrieve the correct site given an old domain. The only flaw here is that since the query groups by domain, stats will be split between old and new metas if both HTTP and HTTPS migrations exist in the data. This is fairly benign, and made all the more so by the fact that the stats page defaults to a 90-day period... And we're well over 90 days past the HTTPS migration now.

...But if you really want to see it, [there's an option for longer look-backs](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/tools/posts/migrated/stats?days=365):

[image: image of the page I just linked to, for those without 10K on SFF]

Answer (score 10):

This is due to the change of the Meta URLs from meta.stack.stackexchange.com to stack.meta.stackexchange.com.

One of those migrations to Meta was pre-URL change, and that URL is no longer the proper address.

Comment: Ah, good thinking. +1 because this is *probably* the explanation, but I'll wait to accept in case an employee comes by to confirm it.