# Mod migration stats are messed up, most likely from https move

Tags: bug, migration, moderator-tools

Looking at the /admin/posts/migrated/stats page, I noticed this oddity:

[image]

Three of them were migrated while it was still on http - and the link on the icon is still without the s, and one of them was from https (with an https link back to the question from before it was migrated, on the /admin/posts/migrated/here page).

Comment: See also: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/293038/278659