# Migration stats pages seem to be broken

Tags: bug, migration, 10k-tools, migrated-questions

I've checked the migration stats pages on the sites I have access to them [English Language Learners](https://ell.stackexchange.com/tools/posts/migrated/stats) and [Movies & TV](https://movies.stackexchange.com/tools/posts/migrated/stats) and the stats don't reflect the actual migrations at all. It seems to be having trouble attributing the migrations to the sites they came from or were sent to.

Here's the ELL page:

[image: ELL Migration Stats page]

As you can see, there are 190 migrations that apparently come out of thin air (most of them are from ELU). The system is able to correctly attribute a few from ELU and one from French. Similarly, in the away column, the two that were migrated away don't note where they were migrated to. In this case, they were both migrated to ELU.

A few months ago we noticed an [odd migration error similar to this that was related to the Meta URL change](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/293038/why-is-one-migration-showing-up-as-to-a-blank-site). I don't think this is related because these questions aren't from Meta to Main site, they are between sites.

Comment: @Shog9 how is this the same problem? 190 questions weren't migrated from Meta to main.

Comment: Both are caused by the system's inability to parse https links

Comment: Ah. That's not what the current answer there says, so I wasn't sure how they were the same. Thanks.

Comment: This was fixed ~11 days ago, but I didn't get notified; I've added [a detailed answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/293038/why-is-one-migration-showing-up-as-to-a-blank-site/303782#303782) on the other post.